# Trouble building tests with Google Test, Clang, and libc++

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, googletest, libc++

I tried building Google Test with the following CMake configuration:

```
$ CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang++" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -U__STRICT_ANSI__" cmake ../source
```

Building shows CMake picked the right compiler, but my compiler flags aren't passing through:

```
$ VERBOSE=1 make
...
/Users/jfreeman/local/bin/clang++    -I/Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source/include -I/Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source      -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1   -o CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o -c /Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source/src/gtest-all.cc
...
/Users/jfreeman/local/bin/clang++    -I/Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source/include -I/Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source      -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1   -o CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o -c /Users/jfreeman/work/googletest/source/src/gtest_main.cc
```

The end goal is that I want my project, which builds with Clang and libc++, to have tests built with Google Test. That means I need Google Test built with libc++ as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using variables on the command line with CMake sometimes requires the -D (for Define) flag.

```
    $ cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang++" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -U__STRICT_ANSI__"  ../source
```

Comment: I had to add `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="... -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=1"` to make it work.